# Get all.polarity value from qdap package results in R

Tags: r, rstudio, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis, qdap

[image: Screenshot of the data frame result]I wanted to do sentimental analysis in R using qdap package. 
It gives out a data frame containing all.all, all.wc, all.polarity, all.pos.words, all.neg.words etc.

I want to extract the values of all.polarity, all.pos.words,all.neg.words but when i use
sentiment$all.polarity or sentiment$all.pos.words,

I get NULL in result.

> dput(head(sentiment))

```
list(structure(list(all = c("all", "all", "all"), wc = c(44L, 
1L, 1L), polarity = c(-0.422115882408869, 0, 0), pos.words = list(
    "-", "-", "-"), neg.words = list(c("disappointed", "issue"
), "-", "-"), text.var = c("list(list(content = \"  misleaded  icici bank customer care  branch excutive    really disappointed   bank dont know  steps   take  get  issue fixed\", meta = list(author = character(0), datetimestamp = list(sec = 20.097678899765, min = 51, hour = 11, mday = 6, mon = 6, year = 115, wday = 1, yday = 186, isdst = 0), description = character(0), heading = character(0), id = \"1\", language = \"en\", origin = character(0))))", 
"list()", "list()")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("all", 
"wc", "polarity", "pos.words", "neg.words", "text.var"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(all = c("all", "all", "all"), wc = c(61L, 
    1L, 1L), polarity = c(0, 0, 0), pos.words = list("led", "-", 
        "-"), neg.words = list("expire", "-", "-"), text.var = c("list(list(content = \" didnt know   customer banking  icici   years will  led    people   looking  student travel card   staff  mg road     treat customers  tried  offer  card  wud expire  one year n told  get  new card  one year    dont know\", meta = list(author = character(0), datetimestamp = list(sec = 20.3989679813385, min = 51, hour = 11, mday = 6, mon = 6, year = 115, wday = 1, yday = 186, isdst = 0), description = character(0), heading = character(0), id = \"1\", language = \"en\", origin = character(0))))", 
    "list()", "list()")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("all", 
    "wc", "polarity", "pos.words", "neg.words", "text.var"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(all = c("all", "all", "all"), wc = c(58L, 
    1L, 1L), polarity = c(0, 0, 0), pos.words = list("top", "-", 
        "-"), neg.words = list("worst", "-", "-"), text.var = c("list(list(content = \"  asked   staff    can upgrade  platinum  coral card   documentation  fee will  involoved  even  receiving  card poeple sill keep calling   top      levied  rs joining fee    interested  paying     card  one   worst customer care   experienced\", meta = list(author = character(0), datetimestamp = list(sec = 20.648964881897, min = 51, hour = 11, mday = 6, mon = 6, year = 115, wday = 1, yday = 186, isdst = 0), description = character(0), heading = character(0), id = \"1\", language = \"en\", \n    origin = character(0))))", 
    "list()", "list()")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("all", 
    "wc", "polarity", "pos.words", "neg.words", "text.var"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(all = c("all", "all", "all"), wc = c(59L, 
    1L, 1L), polarity = c(-0.494717861727131, 0, 0), pos.words = list(
        "-", "-", "-"), neg.words = list(c("long time", "long time", 
    "disappointed"), "-", "-"), text.var = c("list(list(content = \" applied   credit card   corporate scheme long time back got  verification call also long time back initially   getting  least  response   executive  now    longer picking   call neither letting  know  status   application extremely disappointed   service\", meta = list(author = character(0), datetimestamp = list(sec = 20.8989698886871, min = 51, hour = 11, mday = 6, mon = 6, year = 115, wday = 1, yday = 186, isdst = 0), description = character(0), heading = character(0), id = \"1\", \n    language = \"en\", origin = character(0))))", 
    "list()", "list()")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("all", 
    "wc", "polarity", "pos.words", "neg.words", "text.var"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(all = c("all", "all", "all"), wc = c(66L, 
    1L, 1L), polarity = c(0.0246182981958665, 0, 0), pos.words = list(
        c("work", "support"), "-", "-"), neg.words = list("disappointed", 
        "-", "-"), text.var = c("list(list(content = \" otp service   working    used  work   month     decided  change everything im  getting  otp sms   registered mobile number ive tried contacting  customer support several times   keep asking   send  sms   despite  done  several times  several days  havent received  otps ever really disappointed\", meta = list(author = character(0), datetimestamp = list(sec = 21.1935319900513, min = 51, hour = 11, mday = 6, mon = 6, year = 115, wday = 1, yday = 186, isdst = 0), description = character(0), \n    heading = character(0), id = \"1\", language = \"en\", origin = character(0))))", 
    "list()", "list()")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("all", 
    "wc", "polarity", "pos.words", "neg.words", "text.var"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(all = c("all", "all", "all"), wc = c(50L, 
    1L, 1L), polarity = c(-0.282842712474619, 0, 0), pos.words = list(
        "-", "-", "-"), neg.words = list(c("pathetic", "lied"
    ), "-", "-"), text.var = c("list(list(content = \"  pathetic service  behavior  icici bank   facing  past  days icici executive lied  luring   upgrade  debit card terms  conditions  just opposite   booklet   received    told  phone\", meta = list(author = character(0), datetimestamp = list(sec = 21.4258019924164, min = 51, hour = 11, mday = 6, mon = 6, year = 115, wday = 1, yday = 186, isdst = 0), description = character(0), heading = character(0), id = \"1\", language = \"en\", origin = character(0))))", 
    "list()", "list()")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("all", 
    "wc", "polarity", "pos.words", "neg.words", "text.var"), class = "data.frame"))
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Please show some reproducible example data.  For guidelines, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Using polarity function of qdap package on any text produces same data frame

Comment: May be it is the case.  Could you update your post with some text?

Comment: i was trying to post the screenshots but didnt had the required priviledges

Comment: Please don't post images as others have to manually type it from the images.  The link I commented above gives ideas about posting.

Comment: Its a result after using polarity function

Comment: I tried the example from the help page of `?polarity`. i.e. `poldat2 <- with(mraja1spl, polarity(dialogue,list(sex, fam.aff, died)))`, but it is not giving this `all.poswords` or `all.neg.words`.   Can you show the code you used or if you can quote the example from the help page, it would be great

Comment: It was a text file named data. I used sentiment = polarity(data) after removing spaces,stopwords, numbers etc. The output table is shown in the pic above. I just need the negative words and polarity. I had used sentiment$all.polarity but its giving NULL.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am not getting the same output with the example in the help page.  It may be better to post the dput output. i..e `dput(head(sentiment))`

Comment: Can you try `head(sentiment[[1]][1])`  If you get the all.all, then probably, you can extend that to `sentiment[[1]][2]` etc.

Comment: head(sentiment[[1][3]]) works. Thanks

Comment: You could post that as a solution and close this.

Comment: It's a list not a dataframe.  Use `str` to see.  The examples give more on accessing the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me -

```
 library(qdap)

 text <- "I am liking the work "  # the text for which polarity score is needed

 sentiment <- polarity(text) #make the call 

 sentiment$all$pos.words # returns the positive words detected by the algo
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "liking" "work"  

 sentiment$all$polarity # returns the sentence polarity score 
 #[1] 0.8944272
```

Comment: Or at the very least a bit of output